# Call two different functions on same <td> having span, jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a small issue, like,

I want to call two functions for same `td`, 
1. if user clicks on td , call a function, 
2. when user clicks on span of the `td`.

**Jquery:**

```
 if (jQuery(tr).find("td span").hasClass('drill_icon')) {
        console.log('DRILL DOWN : ');    
    } else {
        console.log('SELECT/UNSELCT : ');
    }
```

I tried the above jquery conditioning, but did not help.

Please help me, how to check if the user clicked on td, or if the user clicked on span, 
I know, if I use two `td`, then finding can be easy:

```
<td title="Afghanistan" _colid="1" style="width: 95%; overflow: hidden;">Afghanistan<span class="right drill_icon"></span></td>
```

Comment: try this `$("tr td span.drill_icon")` which will return matching elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

#### 1. Hook up two handlers:

One for the `span`:

```
$("span.drill_icon").click(function() {
    // Do your thing here

    // Stop the event
    return false;
});
```

...and one on the `td`:

```
$("selector for td").click(function() {
    // Do the thing
});
```

If the click is on the `span`, that handler will get called first, and since it stops the event, the other handler won't get called at all.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ukinek/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ukinek/1/edit)

#### 2. Use one handler and do the check on click

Or use one handler but then seen whether the click was in the `span`:

```
$("selector for td").click(function(e) {
    // In the span?
    if ($(e.target).closest("span.drill_icon")[0]) {
        // Yes
    }
    else {
        // No
    }
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ukinek/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ukinek/2/edit)

Comment: Hey T.J. Crowder,
 Thanks Very much, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

use two click function

```
 $("span.drill_icon").click(function() {
   //span is clicked..
   spanClickedFunction();
   return false;  //to make sure td click is not called here..this stops the event and td handler won't be called;
});

$("tr td").click(function() {
   //td is clicked..
   tdClickedFunction();

});

function spanClickedFunction(){
  alert('span clicked');
}

function tdClickedFunction(){
  alert('td clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table td span.drill_icon").click(function (e){
   alert('Clicked on span');
   e.stopPropagation(); // stops further propagation
});

$("table td").click(function (){
   alert('Clicked on td');
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MKsZA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 click handlers. One for the TD and one for the span.

```
$("td").click(function() {
    //code that executes when clicked in the td but not in span
});

$("td span.drill_icon").click(function(event) {
    //code that executes when clicked in the span

    //prevents that the click-event gets fired on the parent elements
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("td").click(function () {
            alert("click on td");
        });

        $("td span").click(function () {
            alert("click on span");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The important thing to notice is the return false in span click handler which prevents the event to propagate to its DOM parents. I think jquery calls event.stopPropagation() which does this thing.

I see it's hard to test with your example, may I suggest:

- replace _colid with id
- add text to span since I see your text is in td
- add some border to the span (just for test) so you can see where the span actually finishes